# MongoDB: Rename field in array with nested document

Tags: mongodb

I struggle to rename a fieldname within a nested document in an array in MongoDB:

```js
[
  {
    "parserErgebnis": [
      {
        "values": {
          "NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "1000/13138/1082"
          },
          "ANYTHING": "bla",
          "BLUBB": "bla"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parserErgebnis": [
      {
        "values": {
          "NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "1000/13138/1083"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parserErgebnis": [
      {
        "values": {
          "ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "1000/13138/1084"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER must be renamed to ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER.

So, the result should look like that:

```js
[
  {
    "parserErgebnis": [
      {
        "values": {
          "ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "1000/13138/1082"
          },
          "ANYTHING": "bla",
          "BLUBB": "bla"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parserErgebnis": [
      {
        "values": {
          "ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "1000/13138/1083"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parserErgebnis": [
      {
        "values": {
          "ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "1000/13138/1084"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this which doesn't work. The problem is that parserErgebnis.values.ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER is throwing an error. What works is just ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER, but with that values sub-document is gone.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "parserErgebnis.values.NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER": {
    $exists: true
  }
},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      parserErgebnis: {
        $map: {
          input: "$parserErgebnis",
          as: "parserErgebnis",
          in: {
            "parserErgebnis.values.ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER": "$$parserErgebnis.values.NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Any ideas? I appreciate your help.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/N6pjj8J_Vme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "parserErgebnis.values.NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER": {
    $exists: true
  }
},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      parserErgebnis: {
        $map: {
          input: "$parserErgebnis",
          as: "parserErgebnis",
          in: {
            "values": {
              ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER: "$$parserErgebnis.values.NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UNgQMuFClkh)

**Update**

A generic solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         "parserErgebnis.values.NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER": { $exists: true }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         "parserErgebnis.values": {
            $map: {
               input: "$parserErgebnis.values",
               in: { $objectToArray: "$$this" }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         parserErgebnis: {
            $map: {
               input: "$parserErgebnis",
               as: "parserErgebnis",
               in: {
                  values: {
                     $map: {
                        input: "$$parserErgebnis.values",
                        as: "value",
                        in: {
                           $concatArrays: [
                              {
                                 $filter: {
                                    input: "$$value",
                                    cond: { $ne: ["$$this.k", "NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER"] }
                                 }
                              },
                              [{
                                 k: "ORDNUNGSBEGRIFFAUFTRAGGEBER",
                                 v: {
                                    $let: {
                                       vars: {
                                          val: {
                                             $filter: {
                                                input: "$$value",
                                                cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", "NUTZERKENNUNGAUFTRAGGEBER"] }
                                             }
                                          }
                                       },
                                       in: { $first: "$$val.v" }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }]
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         "parserErgebnis": {
            $map: {
               input: "$parserErgebnis",
               as: "parserErgebnis",
               in: {
                  values: {
                     $first: {
                        $map: {
                           input: "$$parserErgebnis.values",
                           as: "value",
                           in: { $arrayToObject: "$$value" }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: However, additional fields ANYTHING and BLUBB are gone

Comment: @jens_laufer [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RTjIOEYB-Oj) might be a more generic solution